# Display message for user VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA , I'm trying  to make a macro that show a message to the user when he forgot to fill a case.
all comments are welcome ,

Comment: Dear POLOS, you should describe what you want in more details. Please, provide the code you have already developed, so we can analyze and try to help you.

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting to highlight the cell(s) yellow when they are empty?

Answer (score 2):

UGH you didnt even bother trying the bare minimum did you?

You know you learn ALL of this stuff in the first few pages of EVERY tutorial right?

I guess ill help though

```
 If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "" Then
      MsgBox("You Cannot leave this cell empty")
End if
```

Here are some good tutorials. Please do the bare minimum of self teaching and make sure to come to Stack Overflow with *specific* coding questions.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/

http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-VBA-Tutorial.html

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html

This took me less time to find than your post prolly took to write out, just saying.

Comment: @Doug Coats  sorry i'm doing my best here  i'm working for a company that everyday want something from me , so I'm looking for quick answers

Comment: LOL naw let him have at it. Besides my posts are full SO material unless I give @Mat'sMug something to do :D

Comment: @POLOSTutorials well dude hate to tell you that Im likely the only person here who will even entertain basic hand holding, and even I have my limits. Look at the tutorials i pointed you to, it should help significantly

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with another idea:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

    If Trim(Cells(1, 1)) = "" Then

        MsgBox "Do not leave"
        Sheets(1).Select
        Cells(1, 1).Select

    End If

End Sub
```

If you put this code in the worksheet, not in a module, it would work. 
Make sure, that you put it on the first Workbook, not in a module. E.g., here:

[image]

Depending on what exactly you are doing, you can also put similar procedure in a Worksheet (ThisWorkbook on the picture above) and use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event, to disallow users to leave.

Comment: ,@Doug It shows Do not Leave everytime  but it doesn't  show where should I fill What I want to exactly   ( I got a table with information to be fill by the user and he should fill every single case ) so I need to  display a message for him when he forgot to fill something

Comment: It is selecting  a filled Case :'(      code
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

    If Trim(Cells(1, 460)) = "" Then

        MsgBox "Do not leave"
        Sheets("Feuil1").Select
        Cells(1, 460).Select

    End If

End Sub

Comment: If it is like this (https://pastebin.com/TQ7KdAFQ) , and you have put the code in the correct Sheet in the VBE, this should not be the case. Cells(1,460) is `QR1`. Are you sure you need `QR1` and not `A460`?